# discord.py mini-game command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to make a command where You can catch phoenixes and randomly it'll ping you and the member and if you type `catch` it'll add one point to your counter. However I tried and the furthest it got was it pinging us to type `catch`. When I typed `catch` it didn't respond.

```py
@client.command(aliases=["ctp", "capturethephoenix"])
async def catchthephoenix(ctx, member : discord.Member=None):
  points = {ctx.author: 0, member: 0}
  random_time = random.randrange(30)
  if member == None:
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, You need to mention a member to play with.")
  if member == client.user:
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Hey! Are you trying to catch me??! Mention someone else.")
  if member.bot == True:
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, You can't play with a bot.")
  else:
    game = True
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} and {member.mention}, I will alert you when a phoenix is found so you can catch it.")
    def check(m):
      return m.author.id == ctx.author.id
    while True:
      try:
        message = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=45)
        await asyncio.sleep(random_time)
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} and {member.mention}, A Phoenix has been found! Type `catch` to catch it!")
        if message.author.id == member.id and message.content.lower() == "catch":
          points[member] += 1
          await ctx.send(f"{member.name} has caught the phoenix! They have **{points[member]}** point(s)!")
        elif message.author.id == ctx.author.id and message.content.lower() == "catch":
          points[ctx.author] += 1
          await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.name} has caught the phoenix! They have **{points[ctx.author]}** point(s)!")
      except:
        game = False
        embed = discord.Embed(
          color = embed_color,
          title = "Game Over",
          description = "No one caught the Phoenix in time so the game is over. Final Scores Below.")
        embed.add_field(name = f"{member.name}'s score", value = f"{points[member]}")
        embed.add_field(name = f"{ctx.author.name}'s score", value = f"{points[ctx.author]}")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "it didn't respond". Was there an error? Have you tried any debugging to determine where exactly the code doesn't function as intended?

Comment: When I typed catch there was no response from the bot nor was there an error. Here is a picture of what happened.

https://imgur.com/a/5U5Pe8a

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling `client.wait_for()` before the `await asyncio.sleep()` and `await ctx.send()` statements (inside the `try` clause). The `client.wait_for()` call should be *after*.

```py
@client.command(aliases=["ctp", "capturethephoenix"])
async def catchthephoenix(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    points = {ctx.author: 0, member: 0}
    random_time = random.randrange(30)

    game = False
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send("...")
    elif member == client.user:
        await ctx.send("...")
    elif member.bot:
        await ctx.send("...")
    else:
        game = True

    await ctx.send(...)
    while game:
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(random_time)
            await ctx.send(...)
            message = await client.wait_for(
                "message",
                check=lambda m: m.author.id == ctx.author.id,
                timout=45.0
            )
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            game = False
            ...
        if not message.content.lower() == "catch":
            continue
        if message.author.id == member.id:
            ...
        elif message.author.id == ctx.author.id:
            ...
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. One last thing, How can I make it check if a game is already running?

Comment: @Phoenix Instead of `while True`, you could write `while game`. Then, you can implement that into a command or another case for checking the content of `message` (e.g., `if message.content.lower() == "running":`).